# Python: extract unique id from file name

Tags: python, parsing, text

I have a `csv` file that contains a list of authors in the `MLA` in the format.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

If I check the column name I have:

```
df['name']

'van der Hilst, Rob, Chen, Min, Huang, Hui, Niu, Fenglin, Yao, Huajian'
'Malanotte-Rizzoli, Paola, Eltahir, Elfatih, Wei, Jun, Xue, Pengfei'
'Bowring, Samuel, Hoke, Gregory, Schmitz, Mark'
```

I want to extract the `Firstname+Familyname` and assign to it a unique ID. For instance I want `Rob van der Hilst = 0`, `Min Chen = 1` and so on.

Comment: So it's always `last name1, first name1, last name2, first name2,...`?

Comment: Yes it should be always in this format

Comment: It is always in this fomat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand your question correct, then you can take advantage of the python string sclicing and other fancy language features

here is the code and explanation:

load names

```
names = 'van der Hilst, Rob, Chen, Min, Huang, Hui, Niu, Fenglin, Yao, Huajian' + \
        'Malanotte-Rizzoli, Paola, Eltahir, Elfatih, Wei, Jun, Xue, Pengfei' + \
        'Bowring, Samuel, Hoke, Gregory, Schmitz, Mark'
```

split names on comma followed by space:

```
names = names.split(', ')
```

use python slicing to extract first and last names, names looks as follows:
['van der Hilst', 'Rob', 'Chen', 'Min', 'Huang' ...]

slicing takes the form of scalar[start:stop:steps], we thus start at the first first name and first larst name, and take steps of size 2 to get all the other last or first names, if 'stop' is empty it means 'continue til the end'

```
last_names = names[::2]
first_names = names[1::2]
```

finally we use a dictionary comprehention to map names to ids, to do this we use:

the zip function to stick last and first names together

the enumerate function to assign numbers

the '%s %s' to concatinate the first and last name

```
names = {'%s %s' % (fn, ln) : _id for _id, (fn, ln) in enumerate(zip(first_names, last_names))}
```

the final code is:

```
names = 'van der Hilst, Rob, Chen, Min, Huang, Hui, Niu, Fenglin, Yao, Huajian' + \
        'Malanotte-Rizzoli, Paola, Eltahir, Elfatih, Wei, Jun, Xue, Pengfei' + \
        'Bowring, Samuel, Hoke, Gregory, Schmitz, Mark'
names = names.split(', ')
last_names = names[::2]
first_names = names[1::2]

names = {'%s %s' % (fn, ln) : _id for _id, (fn, ln) in enumerate(zip(first_names, last_names))}
```

Comment: @emax, you are welcome, if you are new to python I would recomend you googeling all the words such as slicing and dictionary comprehension and all the functions such as zip and enumerate becaue that would be a wise long term investment in mastering python

Comment: Nice answer - was just about to answer like this.

Comment: @erip, ofcourse: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."